How to add multiple table in a single sheet using Laravel Excel
I've been trying to include multiple tables in a single sheet using FromViews but it's always ended up broken.
this is how my code looks like
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <table>
    ...
   </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <table>
    ...
   </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>


what I want to achieve :

and how to use border in blade rather than using withEvents? thank you.


I've been trying to include multiple tables in a single sheet using FromViews but it's always ended up broken.

In my experience, you can't do that. You're stuck having to either figure out how to get the data where it needs to be or using PHPSpreadsheet's setCellValue method.

how to use border in blade rather than using withEvents?

PHPSpreadsheet understands some inline styles. Border is one of them. You can just use <td style="border: 1px solid black">...</td>.
For more complicated styles? You're stuck having to use the underlying PHPSpreadsheet's styling methods.

I see, so I can't put multiple tables in a sheet?
thank you for the answer, the border one works!

You can't put multiple <table> elements in a sheet but you can have a layout like the one in your image. It's just painful to do with FromView.
